# Mocha before hook not being run before suite

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm new to Node and Mocha and am having difficulty in understanding why Mocha is skipping over my 'before' hook code to create a Json Web Token in the following example:

```js
//index.js
const createJWT = require('./lib/config/createJWT');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

before(async() => {

  const jwt = await createJWT() {
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(jwt);
      }
    )
  }
  const person = createPerson(jwt);

}); //this is where the jwt is created, making it useless for createPerson

describe('My other tests', () => {
it('Customer sign up', async() => {
  const signUpText = await customerSignUp(page, frame);

  expect(signUpText).to.equal("You have signed up")

  });
 });
});
```

The createJWT() method is as follows:

```js
 //createJWT.js
module.exports = async() => {

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://my-website.auth.io/oauth/token',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: '{"client_id":"dew76dw7e65d7w65d7wde"}'
  };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    try {
        console.log(body);
        jwt = body;
        return jwt = body;
    } catch
        (error) {
    }
  });
};
```

When I debug, the setup code is skipped over.  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Your code snippets throw errors. To the problem though, [`before`](https://mochajs.org/#hooks) is local to its `describe` block, so you need to regroup your tests. If you want a global setup, you need to run `before` above  all `describe` blocks.

Comment: @FK82 thank you, hopefully the error handling is a bit neater now?  My issue is that I want ti use the 'jwt' value in the next function down but it is not created until the closing block of 'before' when I debug.  I suspect this is something to do with Promises

Comment: I was talking about that errors are raised when you press "Run code snippet" in your code snippets above. Anyway, I see the problem now, your `request` function is callback based and `createJWT` will generally return before the callback has run. One solution for this is to make `createJWT` return a promise and call its resolve function from the callback in `request`.

Comment: @FK82 ah ok, that makes sense. This stuff is all new to me so I'm learning fast! I've put something that looks basically functional in my question.  Not sure that's quite right syntactically

Comment: No, that won't work. What i meant is that you rewrite `createJWT` itself to return a promise (i.e. `module.exports = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...})`. Then inside the arrow function you add your original function's body with the line `resolve(jwt);` instead of the line `return jwt = body;`. Does this make sense to you or do I need to explain more?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure you need to put the before hook in the same test block for it to be ran before it is processed.
Ex :

```
before(async() => {

  const jwt = await createJWT();

});

describe('My other tests', () => {
  it('Customer sign up', async() => {
    const signUpText = await customerSignUp(page, frame);

    expect(signUpText).to.equal("You have signed up")
  });
});
```

Or :

```
describe('My other tests', () => {
  before(async() => {

    const jwt = await createJWT();

  });
  it('Customer sign up', async() => {
    const signUpText = await customerSignUp(page, frame);

    expect(signUpText).to.equal("You have signed up")
  });
});
```

Furthermore, your `createJwt` method does not return a Promise, which prevents the await from working. You need to do something like this :

```
module.exports = async() => {

  const options = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://my-website.auth.io/oauth/token',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: '{"client_id":"dew76dw7e65d7w65d7wde"}'
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if(error) {
      reject(error);
    }
    resolve(body);
  }));
};
```

Comment: Bethou thank you; I had tried this but it still seem not to work.  I did not explain the question correctly.  I need to retrieve the 'jwt' value and use it in some more setup code as per the updated code.  Let me try some more with the examples you have suggested

Comment: Hello @Steerpike, I think you misunderstood how async/await and promises are working. I Updated the answer with a probably working example. You should read some articles about promises, as async/await is just some syntax sugar over it.